# What is the most standard way to persist data between MVC views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I'm creating a system using ASP.NET MVC for filling out online job applications. It's really just an experiment to familiarize myself with the MVC framework. I'm definitely not a security expert so I just wanted to get some advice here since this web app will be dealing with sensitive information.

The system has a wizard-like set of views. You go from one view to the next filling out the relevant information until the end when you finally submit it.

Each job application is stored in the database with a GUID primary key. Right now I am simply storing that GUID in a hidden field in the view of each page. This makes it easy to update the model in the controller like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExampleAction(FormCollection formValues)
{
    Guid appId = new Guid(Request.Form["ModelId"]); // the GUID stored in the hidden field
    ExampleModel example = db.Entities.Single(e => e.ModelId == appId);

    UpdateModel(example, formValues);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ExampleAction2", new { appId = appId.ToString() });
}
```

I know this is not secure because anyone with any kind of development experience knows you can edit the values of hidden fields in any browser's developer tools. So what's the recommended way to securely get the same results?

Comment: They can edit the field, sure. If they edit it to something invalid, just toss the application. If they edit it to something valid, well how did they get access to someone elses GUID?

Comment: You just want to keep the GUID? One of the keys features at MVC is the routing and verbose URLs. This means that, if there is no problem in showing the ID, put at on the URL, like `jobs/view/GUID` or `jobs/apply/GUID`. Otherwise, I'd keep it at the session

Comment: @Brandon I'm not worried about them hijacking another application--that's virtually impossible. Just interested in hiding implementation details from the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store it in the Session object. That way, you can call it at anytime from anywhere and it will never display on any of your views.
The doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: To go one step further, I would encapsulate this in an interface so that you can easily mock and unit test it later on.

Comment: **`Session`s are evil in a cloud environment** as they are created per server and in a Cloud Hosting, we never know what server is serving the request, and one page could be served from one server, and the next from other ... you will loose everything... use a Cached Layer, in .NET and as an example, MemCached.

Comment: @balexandre re: "created per server" - says who? you can easily use `StateServer` or `SQLServer` modes (or, even `Custom`) per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, just for interest sake I want to leave another option. How you could go about it is parsing the information you get from the first view as a JSON string that you can store in a cookie and then later serialize it when you need it.

This is asuming that the information is safe to store client side. Otherwise it could be an encrypted cookie I suppose. This would address the concerns for cloud computing and load balancers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not post to each step instead of using RedirectToAction? That way you can create a model that contains each step.. for example:

```
class JobApplicationViewModel
{
    public Guid ApplicationGuid { get; set; }
    public StepOne Step1 { get; set; }
    public StepTwo Step2 { get; set; }
    public int CurrentStep { get; set; }
}
```

The step 1 view can post to step 2.. for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult StepTwo(JobApplicationViewModel viewModel)
{
    ServiceLayer.Update(viewModel);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then, the StepTwo view posts to StepThree, StepThree posts to Step4, etc. This makes sense logically, as you're only allowing people to get to any step beyond step 1 by posting the form.

Comment: Well it works, but that's not the best for maintainability, is it? I think forms should post to their own actions for readability. For example, nobody wants to remember that the "ContactInfo" form posts to  the "CareerExperience" action.

Comment: While that is a valid argument.. if the process is StepOne -> StepTwo -> StepThree.. that's a little different. I assumed you were describing the entire process as steps, not as descriptions of the steps, in which case I would not use my suggestion.